# SharePoint 2013 Search Service Endpoint Failure Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, search, search-results, enterprise-search

SharePoint 2013 Search Service not showing search results. Below is the error details.

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to
>   https://myQueryProcessingServer:32844/feb50aff5b52475ba00ffec8d8e1adff/SearchService.svc.
>   This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP
>   protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being
>   aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See
>   server logs for more details.

Below is the error screenshot.

[image]

Search service is crawling fine and all components are UP in the Search Administration.

Any help?

Comment: Is your Search Service Application in the web application service connection list?

Comment: Yes it is. I have tried creating new search service and it worked fine. But still i want to troubleshoot and fix the error of above service as recreating is not the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the Srx reports on your farm to determine if all services are correctly provisioned and communicating. For example, is the SQSS running on your Query Servers?  [SRx Core - SharePoint Search Health Reports](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SRx-Core-SharePoint-Search-d60113e9/)

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I ran that script and it tested my Search Service. Everything appeared fine except SSAEndPointSQSS. I see error on it

SSAEndPointSQSS          Error   {(SearchService.svc) The following WCF service Endpoints cannot be reached:, (SearchService.svc) The following WCF service Endpoints cannot be reached.....

Comment: That is what I thought. Are you running the SSQS on the Query Server(s)? If not be sure to start them.

Comment: Yes they are already running on Query Servers which are my WFEs.

Comment: Can the services be reached? Are you running firewall rules preventing communication? You have to resolve the failures in the report.

Comment: Yes if i manually browse the services on all servers individually, they are accessible over http and https (by showing a certificate error). I believe there is no change in Firewall rules recently. Same error i am noticing on Managed Metadata Service as well. Both services were working fine couple of days back.

Comment: Certificate error?

Comment: Yes that generic message which appears while browsing a https service manually. Screenshot here... https://ibb.co/dzASqk

Comment: You shouldn't have any certificate errors. That is likely your issue. You need to fix that.

Comment: I see. But how i can switch to use HTTP service not HTTPS one? I don't want it to run on HTTPS due to this error. Furthermore, i see the same certificate error on one of my another SharePoint environment but search is working fine there. Could be something else with it?

Comment: Generally you don't need to change any of these settings. The best practice is to use SSL for all server to server communications. It certainly could be "something else". Though, if the SRx reports are failing I would start there.

Comment: I am not sure where to look for this specific error because Diagnostic Logs only shows what i have shared. I believe i have once faced this Endpoint binding error and recreation of services was the only solution.

Comment: If rebuilding is an option I would look at that, you can preserve the admin database and restore it so that you save your settings. (Everything except the Thesaurus if you are using that.) Before that you may want to try an index reset first...I don't think it will help, but it is faster than a rebuild.

Comment: Yes i have tried Index Reset however it didn't help. I had to rebuild it and now search is working fine on the environment. Thank you very much for your active response on this thread. I wish Microsoft must notice this issue as rebuilding is not the solution.

Comment: Glad I helped, can you mark the question as answered?

Comment: I truly appreciate your effort and time on this thread but unfortunately i did not get the fix for this issue. At the end i had to recreate the service which is obviously not the resolution. I could mark this as answer but it would not be justice with other readers who look for the same issue. I have already up-marked your answer as this is the most relevant to our troubleshooting. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

After spending weeks on troubleshooting this issue, i ended up on recreating the **Search Service Application** using the same existing search service databases. No other workaround helped me to make my current Search usable.

**P.S:** Since i have not found a fix to above problem, i'll not mark it as answer.